# Installed Build Tools revision 28.0.3 is corrupted. How to fix this error

Tags: android, android-studio

When I make a new proyect, then Build-make project or try to Run App in an emulator
with sdk api level 28 (Android 9.0 Pie), the Build Output window always show me this error:

```
Installed Build Tools revision 28.0.3 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
```

I removed and reinstalled the sdk several times, and always gives me the same error. I'm using
Android Studio 3.6.3 with build:gradle:3.6.3.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

1) Open the SDK manager by clicking on the icon in the top right of Android Studio.  (Or go to File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK)

2) Open SDK Tools tab

3) At the bottom-right, click "Show Package Details"

4) Find Android SDK Build-Tools and uncheck the checkbox next to 28.0.3

5) Click apply in the bottom of the window. That will delete the component.

6) Now check the checkbox next to 28.0.3

7) Click apply in the bottom of the window. That will reinstall it.

[SDK Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwYaK.png)

Comment: i have the same issue with version 31.0.0-rc5. reinstalling does not work. ideas?

Comment: @or_dvir, using the last stable version should fix it

Comment: @oj7 not possible. i am trying to run an emulator with android 12 and this is the only release for api 31

Comment: @or_dvir api 31 is not the only release. Go to SDK Manager > SDK Tools tab > Select `Android SDK Build-Tools 31-rc5` > click the checbox `Show Package Details` at the bottom. Then select `30.0.3` or any other stable older version. Click apply, and this will install version 30.0.3. Then deselect `31.0.0-rc5` to uninstall it. Once again click apply and it will be unistalled and you are good to go.

Comment: I have the same issue, but did not help, maybe the 31.0.0-rc5 is really corrupt?

Comment: I've the same issue. It seems that 31.xx is corrupted. I've to downgrade to 30.0.3

Comment: Yeah - I was getting the "build is corrupted" originally for `31.0.0`, then all higher builds too (`32.0.0`, `32.1.0-rc1`, `33.0.0`) - even after deleting and re-downloading.  But `30.0.3` worked.

Answer (score 5):

I tried

e.g. Open Your SDK Path: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools

- rename android-S -> 31.0.0-rc5
- copy build-tools\30.0.3\dx.bat -> 31.0.0-rc5\dx.bat
- copy build-tools\30.0.3\lib\dx.jar -> 31.0.0-rc5\lib\dx.jar

then the build should succeed.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66668714/installed-build-tools-revision-30-0-3-is-corrupted
30.0.3 isn't stable, using the last stable version fixed it for me.

Comment: @JacobCelestine yes, but partially. install build tools 31.0.0-rc5 as usual. Then copy `dx.bat` and `lib\dx.jar` to 31.0.0-rc5 folder. I tried on my side and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when I was getting

```
Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
```

The "uninstall and reinstall" technique from @TrackRunner did not work for me.  Downgrading the `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle` did.  Note - upgrading to a higher version like `33.0.0` resulted in the same "corrupted" error.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3' // Used to be 31.0.0
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. How to fix this error**

While executing `quasar -m cordova -T android` I got the Build Tools corrupted error. But on checking the SDK directory `/path-to-sdk/` all the installed sdk versions are listed in the directory.

Ex:
`/path-to-sdk/31.0.0`
`/path-to-sdk/29.0.3` etc

In the later versions especially with the versions upto version 29 and below d8 & dx and d8.jar & dx.jar files are found in both `/path-to-sdk/version` and `/path-to-sdk/version/lib` paths respectively.

But in the latest versions the files dx and dx.jar files are seemed to be omitted in their respective paths, and only the d8 and d8.jar are found.

So on renaming these files from d8 and d8.jar fixes the problem.

Note:
On compiling and building with quasar/cordova frameworks this doesn't seems to affect the integrity of android build tools. However this may affect the project run/build while using android-studio for development.