# Installed build tools revision 30.0.3 is corrupted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

when i build my android application it is giving error "Installed Build Tools revision 30.0.3 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager" i tried to fix this by update my sdk manager but it didn't work. How can i fix this error.

Comment: version 30.0.3 Should work now. What produced this same error for me was version  31.0.0-rc5. All I had to do was to go into the SDK manager and deselect it to uninstall it. Then select 30.0.3 to install it. I was able to build without issues after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try, to install the **stable version** of SDK Build tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ESET antivirus was quarantining `aapt.exe` (breaking the build tools) as "suspicious".