# I Have to add JAVA_HOME to gradle.properties every time I start a new flutter project in vs code! how to solve it once & for all?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, visual-studio-code, java-11

I am starting to learn flutter & by extension, dart.

However! every time I follow a tutorial & start a new project in ***vs code*** I have to go to the file called `gradle.properties` and add `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9` or else I won't be able to run/debug!

Because I get an error saying I need `java 11` while I'm using `1.8` which is ***TOTALLY*** not true because my java_home (& path) variable is set to java 11, which is the directory i add through the previously mentioned line of code.

Please, I do not know what to do, and googling is no longer helping as no result I'm finding is working. I need someone to tell me what to do to solve this... issue because I am sure something can be done once instead of repeating this process every time.

Note: I found on google people saying stuff like:

> Set Gradle jdk path to java 11 in *android studio*

but I do not have that option.

Also, please note that I am still a beginner-level *developer* with little practical experience - Sorry if my question is, well, stupid.

attached images:

- [Gradle Error if gradle.properties not modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdT3P.png)
- [gradle.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv0ry.png)
- [my Android Studio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqND1.png)
- [Android Studio settings found on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a15i4.png)

~Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after updating Flutter. Try to check your JAVA version `java -version` (update it, if it less than 8).
Then update Android SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434900/13506243

This helped me.